# How to filter by value field in a pivot table?

Tags: excel, vba, filter, pivot-table

I am trying to filter "Sum of TEST" value field in my pivot table.

An error message

> Application-defined or object-defined error

shows up at line number 4.

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sum of TEST").PivotFilters.Add _
  Type:=xlValueIsGreaterThan, Value1:=30
```

```vb
Private Sub Filter()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ManualUpdate = True 
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields(2).ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sum of TEST").PivotFilters.Add _
      Type:=xlValueIsGreaterThan, Value1:=30
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").ManualUpdate = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: It is not possible to filter `Values` field. It is possible to filter row/column fields with a condition for its value (`DataField` parameter).

Answer (score -1):

To Filter the Pivot table you will have to parse pivot items and then set the visibility to false for items that you don't want to show. Try the following:

```
Sub Pivot_Filtering()
    Dim pf As PivotField
    Set pf = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotFields("Sum of Test")
    'Clear Out Any Previous Filtering
  pf.ClearAllFilters
  'Enable filtering on multiple items
  pf.EnableMultiplePageItems = True
    For i = 2 To pf.PivotItems.Count
        If pf.PivotItems(i) > 30 Then
            pf.PivotItems(i).Visible = False
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```